# Как сделать так, чтобы в начале блока была расположена картинка на картинке была ещё одна картинка, а справа от картинок был текст?

Tags: html, css

такой блок нужно сверстать, помогите пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]g

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Иными словами, что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: вообще это азы вёрстки. возможно, вам стоит немного поучиться, прежде чем что-то верстать. почитайте про позиционирование, например

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам нужен блок, в котором слева есть картинка, поверх картинки блок с текстом, справа текст и кнопка, и всё это нужно сделать только при помощи html, css, то это можно реализовать следующим образом

```css
.container {
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.block_image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}

.block_text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  top: 330px;
  left: 140px;
}

.block_text h3 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.block_text p {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.block_text2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  right: 20px;
}

.block_text2 h1,
h2,
p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="block_image" src="https://p1.zoon.ru/preview/wWms_WrGbhGaEMwrZJRWhA/2400x1500x85/1/f/a/original_5554908f40c08885758b7356_62f240c5e02141.61633353.jpg" alt="shaverma">
  <div class="block_text">
    <h3>Come and visit us</h3>
    <p>(414) 857-0107</p>
    <p>happytummy@restaurant.com</p>
    <p>837 W. Marshall Lane Marshalltown, IA 50158, Los Angeles</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block_text2">
    <h1>We provide healthy food for your family</h1>
    <h2>lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
    <form action="#">
      <button>More about us</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const btnMoreAbout = document.getElementById("btnMoreAbout");
    const popup = document.getElementById("popup");
    const close = document.getElementById("close");

    btnMoreAbout.addEventListener("click", function () {
        popup.style.display = "block";
    });

    close.addEventListener("click", function () {
        popup.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-align-justify-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.block-img, .block-content {
    flex: 1;
}

.block-img img {
    width: 250px;
}

.btn-more-about {
    padding: 15px 25px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

/*@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .block {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}*/

/* Стили для попапа */
.popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.popup-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #3a3a3a;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.popup h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.popup p {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-img flex-align-justify-center">
            <img src="http://surl.li/mlanj" alt="img">
        </div>
        <div class="block-content flex-align-justify-center">
            <div>
                <h2>We provide healthy food for your family</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since.
                </p>
                <p> It has survived not only five
                    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                    popularised.
                </p>
                <button id="btnMoreAbout" class="btn-more-about">More About Us</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
        <span class="close" id="close">&times;</span>
        <h2>Come and visit us</h2>
        <p>(404) 857 - 0107</p>
        <p>happy@gmail.com</p>
        <p>837 W.Marshall Lane ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пример кода, в котором по клику на кнопку появляеться модальное окно поверх контента